# can't solve $a-2b=3$ & $5b=4a+1$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$a-2b=3\tag1\label1$$
$$5b=4a+1\tag2\label2$$

Coming to \eqref{1}, $a=2b+3$. Substituting that in \eqref{2}, we get
$5b=4(2b+3)+1$.
$5b=8b+12+1$.
$3b=-13$.
$b=-13/3$.

Substituting value of $b$ in \eqref{1}.
$a-2(-13/3)=3$.
$a-(-26/3)=3$.
Adding $26/3$ to both sides.
$a-0=3+26/3$.
$a=35/3$.

Substituting $a$ and $b$ in \eqref{2}.
$5b=4a+1$.
$5(-13/3)=4(35/3)+1$.
$-65/3=4(35/3)+1$.
$-65/3=140/3+1$.
$-65/3=143/3$.
$-65=143$.
But this is not true.

Comment: This line:  $a−(−26/3)=3$ is $a + \frac {26}3= 3$.   So *subtract* $\frac{26]3$ from both sides....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you messed up where you said "Adding 26/3 to both sides." If you check again, you will see that this should actually be "subtracting 26/3 to both sides" since $$a-\left(-\frac{26}{3}\right)=a+\frac{26}{3}=3\implies a=-\frac{17}{3}$$.

Your answer and algebra for $b$ are correct, giving $a=-\frac{17}{3}, b=-\frac{13}{3}$.

Comment: hey i don't see anything wrong in adding 26/3. shouldn't -26/3 + 26/3 cancel each other out

Comment: @YogeshBhatt The previous statement you have says $a-(-\frac{26}{3})=3$. After this, you added $\frac{26}{3}$ to both sides. Instead, you should have $a-(-\frac{26}{3})=a+\frac{26}{3}=3\implies a=-\frac{17}{3}$.

Comment: yeah i definitely understand what you are trying to say and that's the better way. But i don't understand what is wrong in the way i actually did this in

Comment: You are not understanding that the negative of a negative number is a positive number. For example, $-(-x)=x$. In my comment above, your calculation says $a-(-\frac{26}{3})=a-\frac{26}{3}$, which is wrong.

Comment: hey i got it, it's the order of operations where i'm messing up. pls add this to your answer, i'll accept it

Comment: or to be more accurate, i was adding 26/3 just to the latter part instead of adding it to whole expression of equation 1

Comment: @YogeshBhatt Updated! Glad you understood!

Comment: If you have $a -(-\frac {26}3) = 3$ then you will need to add *negative* $\frac {26}3$ to both sides.  Either you have $a+ \frac {26}3 = 3$ and you *subtract* $+\frac {26}3$ from both sides; or you have $a - (-\frac {26}3) =3$ and you will need to *add* $\color{red}-\frac {26}3$ (note the negative sign).  Both give the same result.  But *adding* $\color{red}+\frac {26}3$ to both sides just won't work.